# Change colors for AngularJS Material in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-material

I have tried to change the color of the text in `input` in `AngularJS Material` with `CSS` but somehow haven't got it to work. What am I doing wrong?

This is my input field:

```
<md-input-container>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input ng-model="user.title">
</md-input-container>
```

and this is how I have tried to change the color of the text.

```
<md-input-container style='color:#e52973'>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input style='color:#e52973' ng-model="user.title">
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: Something like `input{background-color:#e52973}` ?

Comment: Where should I put that?

Comment: in your css file, then link it to the html

Comment: How is that different from what I'm doing right now?

Comment: It's not, it's just the convention.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't solve my problem then does it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170476/discussion-between-joelfischerr-and-zohirsalak-cena).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `!important` with your style attributes to override defaults.

Also you just need to apply style on `input` not to `md-input-container` to change color of input text.

So your current code:

```
<md-input-container style='color:#e52973'>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input style='color:#e52973' ng-model="user.title">
</md-input-container>
```

Change to:

```
<md-input-container>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input style='color:#e52973 !important' ng-model="user.title">
</md-input-container>
```

Working codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VxrjEx